# Why are game engines written in C++?

Tags: c++, c, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why has the industry switched from C to C++?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34539/why-has-the-industry-switched-from-c-to-c)

Since many organizations have demonstarated Object orientation in C and we all know its ABI compatibility that C++ lacks, why game engines are written in C++??

Is there any reason other than easy object orientation??

Comment: Because C++ is the "most high-level-looking" low-level programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there are going to be strong and varied opinions on the matter. Surely you can implement object oriented principles in C. Yet having the features built into the language helps facilitate the issue and the template support you will find hugely pivotal not only in your own code but in utilizing the most popular libraries today.

Just because you are using a C++ compile does not mean that you are using the C++ language features either. Some games are mainly written in C but only utilizing the C++ compiler benefits.